# Add new column with a list of the matching values between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, list-comprehension

I have 2 dataframes with the following structure:

DF1

```
ItemID     Item
Id1        Item1
Id2        Item2
Id3        Item3
...        ...
1000       Item1000
```

DF2

```
Index     ListOfItems
0         [Item1]
1         [Item1, Item3, Item5]
2         [Item2, Item3]
...       ...
N         [NItems]
```

This will be my expected output:

```
Index     ListOfItems               ListOfIds
0         [Item1]                   [Id1]
1         [Item1, Item3, Item5]     [Id1, Id3, Id5]
2         [Item2, Item3]            [Id2, Id3]
...       ...                       ...
N         [NItems]                  [NIds]
```

which is matching the ListOfItmes of the second Dataframe with the Ids of the first Dataframe and create the list of Ids in a new column

This is done over a large dataframe that is constantly changing, so performance is important. I have tried some approaches but the performance is pretty poor.

Comment: Could you change DF2 so that you don't need to have lists in the dataframe?  Your performance might be a lot better if you instead use DF1 with 1 row per item, then add columns for whatever is causing the items to be in certain lists.  For example, col 'source1' would get a 1 for Item 1, 0 for all other items, 'source2' would get a 1 for Item1, Item3, Item5.  Then filter the df to source1 == 1 to generate a list of of the items for source1.

Comment: Unofrotunately I can't do that as the dF2 comes from a specific DB with that information as I present in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df2['ListOfIds'] = df2['ListOfItems'].apply(lambda x: df1[df1['Item'].isin(x)].index.to_list())
```

**SAMPLE DATA:**

```py
>>> df1
         Item
ItemID       
Id1     Item1
Id2     Item2
Id3     Item3

>>> df2
                 ListOfItems
Index                       
0                    [Item1]
1      [Item1, Item3, Item5]
2             [Item2, Item3]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
                 ListOfItems   ListOfIds
Index                                   
0                    [Item1]       [Id1]
1      [Item1, Item3, Item5]  [Id1, Id3]
2             [Item2, Item3]  [Id2, Id3]
```

The solution above expects you to have  the values in `ListOfItems` columns to be lists instead of string, if it is not list, you can do the following to convert it to list from  string:

```py
df2['ListOfItems'] = df2['ListOfItems'].str[1:-1].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: [i.strip() for  i in x])
```

Comment: This works very well, thanks for your help. The columns are actual lists so the first option worked just fine, but it is always good to have the string-toList option.

Answer (score 0):

`df2=df2.replace(regex={'\[':'','\]':''})`#Strip corner brackets

#in df2 make ListOfItems a list and explode, Create new column called

```
ListOfIds and map over the ids
df2=df2.assign(ListOfItems=df2['ListOfItems'].str.split(',')).explode('ListOfItems').assign(ListOfIds=df2['ListOfItems'].map(dict(zip(df1['Item'], df1['ItemID']))))
```

#Groupby Index and age list

```
df2.groupby('Index').agg(list)
```